# On the $\mathsf{LCM}$ of a set of integers defined by moduli of powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, divisors-multiples, probabilistic-number-theory

For integers $a,b,t$ define $$\mathcal R_t(a,b)=\{q\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\min(a^t,b^t)]: a^t\equiv b^t\bmod q\}$$ and $\mathsf{LCM}(\mathcal R_t(a,b))$ to be $\mathsf{LCM}$ of all entries in $\mathcal R_t(a,b)$.

Similar reasoning to [On $\mathsf{LCM}$ of a set of integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362221/on-mathsflcm-of-a-set-of-integers) gives $$\mathsf{LCM}(\mathcal R_t(a,b))\leq\mathsf{LCM}(T_t(a,b))$$ where $T_t(a,b)$ is defined as $$T_t(a,b)=\Big\{q\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\infty]:q|(a^t-b^t)\Big\}.$$

> If $a,b\in\big[\frac r2,r\big]$ hold and are coprime then what is the probability $\mathsf{LCM}(\mathcal R_t(a,b))<\beta r^{t-\alpha}$ at some $\alpha\in(0,t)$ and $\beta>0$?

Comment: Do you mean $a,b$ are chosen randomly?

Comment: Yeah but on set of coprimes but I think without coprime condition and coprime condition should be same.

Comment: We have $\mathrm{LCM}(T_t(a,b))=|a^t-b^t|$. On the other hand, the equality $\mathrm{LCM}(R_t(a,b))=\mathrm{LCM}(T_t(a,b))$ does not always hold.

Comment: $q|(a^t-b^t)\iff a^t\equiv b^t\bmod q$ and thus we can take $LCM$ of all $q$ with $q|(a^t-b^t)$ which is exactly all $q$ with $a^t\equiv b^t\bmod q$?

Comment: I see $\infty$ and $\min(a^t,b^t)$?

Comment: Corrected definition of $\mathcal R_t(a,b)$

Comment: I corrected defintion now (I did not necessitate $b+1<a<2b$).

Comment: $9^7\equiv 7^7\bmod 1979713\implies 1979713\in\mathcal R_7(9,7)$ and so $\mathsf{LCM}(\mathcal R_7(9,7))>1979713\not<2$ no (and in fact $2\in\mathcal R_7(9,7)\wedge\mathsf{GCD}(2,1979713)=1\implies\mathsf{LCM}(\mathcal R_7(9,7))=3959426=\mathsf{LCM}(T_7(9,7))$)?

Comment: Ok,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: With the modified definition, $T_t(a,b)=R_t(a,b)$ (if $a^t\ne b^t$) and the lcm of either is $|a^t-b^t|$, so what is the point of all these definitions?

Comment: I wrote $\min(a^t,b^t)$ before instead of $|a^t-b^t|$ in definition of $R$. I made a mistake in making equality of $R$ and $T$. With $\min(a^t,b^t)$ the probability question made sense. Corrected now. I was thinking about coprimes and did not think of scenario when $b\ll a$ held.

Comment: @VS.: Why do you need to define $T_t(a,b)$ while we simply have $\mathrm{LCM}(T_t(a,b))=|a^t-b^t|$ ?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Similarity of definitions contrast to difference in content.